# Why doesn't this absolute import work in Python?

Tags: python, import, python-2.6

I've got two Python 2.6 files, `/code/x/X.py`:

```
import imp
print 'running'
logging = imp.load_source('logging', '/code/y/logging.py')
```

... and `/code/y/logging.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import logging as _logging

import sys, os
print sys.path
print os.getcwd()
print _logging
```

Running `X.py` prints:

```
running
['/code/x', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
/code/x
<module 'logging' from '/code/y/logging.py'>
```

Why doesn't the `from __future__ import absolute_import` force the `import logging` import to be an absolute one, instead of a local one?  In other words, why don't I see the system logging module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turns out to be the `imp.load_source` command.  The first argument is the name it registers the module under, and subsequent imports will first look in the loaded modules before looking in the path.  Changing the line to use a different name, like:

```
logging = imp.load_source('logx', '/code/y/logging.py')
```

... fixes the problem.

Comment: Your issue actually solves my solution... if that makes sense. I often get the same problem when not using `imp.load_source`. Even when you import `absolute_import`, it will still look in the script directory before the system path. I usually "solve" this by popping `sys.path[0]` - but when using `imp.load_source` and setting the import as a system module name, it still gets overridden. So using `imp.load_source` and not choosing a system module name is a nice solution - better than popping `sys.path[0]`. So thanks. :)